# How do I change the font color using SCSS when it has an imported stylesheet in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, sass

I am not able to change any font/text colors in my div (using the standard methods), and I think the import of "...theme.scss" is blocking these changes (?), I have never used SCSS.  Specifically I want to change just the phone numbers (all) text to red.  I can make other changes, so I know the .scss is hooked up.  I would like to add the red text to an existing style if possible.

html...

```
<div class="contact">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <div class="contact-footer">
    <p><strong>For any other questions, please contact...</strong></p>
    <div class="contact-footer-container">
      <div class="contact-subcontainer">
      <div class="contact-card"><p>Publications<br>Phone: <a href="tel:1-800-123-4567">1-800-123-4567</a><br> <a href="some@something.com">some@something.com</a></p></div>
      <div class="contact-card"><p>Product Support<br>Toll-Free: <a href="tel:1-800-123-4567">1-800-123-4567</a><br>
        Direct: <a href="tel:1-000-123-4567"> 1-000-123-4567</a><br> Fax:  1-000-123-4567
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.scss...

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import '../../some-material-theme.scss';


p {
    font-family: $font-family;
    font-size: $text-medium;
}

.contact-footer {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 15px;
}
.contact-footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
.contact-subcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.contact-card {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.contact-card > p {
    line-height: 150%;
}
mat-icon {
    font-size: 18px;
}
a {    
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work...
in component.scss file

```
.red-text {
color: red;
}
```

in template

```
<a href="tel:1-800-123-4567" class="red-text">1-800-123-4567</a>
```

if that doesn't work then there's an issue somewhere else in your code, maybe the scss is not being loaded in @Component or something like that.

Comment: This did work for me, thank you.  I thought I could add the red color to one of the existing styles/class, but could not get that working.

Answer (score 0):

Check `@Component` decorator has `stylesUrls`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-comp',
  templateUrl: './maincomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maincomp.component.scss']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working, you may need to put all imports and global stylings in **styles.scss**, inside **/src/** folder which will be made available globally for your all components, additionally you may define custom classes and use as per requirements. For e.g. in **styles.scss**:

```
/* Global styles and imports */

@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import '../../some-material-theme.scss';

/* General styles */

.color-red {
    color: red;
}

.color-orange {
    color: orange;
}

.color-green {
    color: green;
}
```

Check if **styles.scss** is configured properly in **angular.json** or you can add it for e.g.:

```
"build": {
    "options": {
         ....,
         "index": "src/index.html",
         "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
         ....
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I agree to suhas that you must import the styles globally i.e. in `styles.scss`. On another note, importing theme styling might override you base css changes, specially bootstrap/material themes. If you are not getting any run time error in console, you can check the particular `<a>` element styles by inspecting the element.

In case you apply any additional class to change the color (e.g. `.color-red`), you must see it in style section of inspect element section and if it is striked-out, meaning your css change is overridden by material css. In such case, you might need to add `!important` at the end of css rule.

```
// HTML
<a class="color-red" href="tel:1-000-123-4567"> 1-000-123-4567</a>


// SCSS
.color-red {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that importing a theme could override base css, and how to check by inspecting, very helpful.